# MultipleDetailViews - Animate Transition Between Views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uisplitviewcontroller, transition

Using Apples MultipleDetailViews Example, Has anyone been able to animate transitions between the detailView when switching detailViews?

The MultipleDetailViews Example only instantly switches views out of the Box. I need this to be animated, possibly using one of the ModalTransitionStyle.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with that example, sorry....

But I have used these methods

```
+[ UIView transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion: ]
+[ UIView transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion: ]
```

to cross-fade between subviews in a view.